# Express router order of request executions: `/state/:params` vs `/state/absolute-path`

Tags: node.js, express

If I have two *REST endpoints*:

```
app.get('/something/:id', ...handlers);
app.get('/something/else', ...handlers);
```

And I send a request to `http://host:port/something/else`

Is there a way to make Express router execute the endpoint with absolute path first (`/something/else`) before executing the one that matches the query params (`/something/:id`)?

I understand that I can reverse the order of invocation and specify the endpoint with query params last. But logically speaking, absolute path should take priority over query params and I believe that's the default behaviour for Koa.js

Comment: change the order of routes, make the else on on top and the parametered one below. it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the more specific route first and the wildcard route second.   Routes are matched in order and the first one that matches handles the request and the others are not then processed.  So, put the more specific route for `/something/else` before the `/something/:id` and you will see the `/something/else` route work properly when that's the URL.

```
// put wildcard route last and more specific route definitions first
// routes are matched in the order they are defined
app.get('/something/else', ...handlers);
app.get('/something/:id', ...handlers);
```

This does raise the question why you have designed this potential conflict into your URL scheme in the first place.  You've essentially overloaded the `id` namespace and have reserved at least one id value for your own use.  This can be managed by careful ordering of the route definitions, but it would generally be better if you didn't have this conflict in your URL design in the first place.

> Is there a way to make Express router execute the endpoint with absolute path first ('/something/else') before executing the one that matches the query params ('/something/:id')?

Yes, define the more specific route first.

> I understand that I can reverse the order of invocation and specify the endpoint with query params last. But logically speaking, absolute path should take priority over query params and I believe that's the default behaviour for Koa.js

You asked about Express.  It matches routes in the order you've defined them. It doesn't try to guess which route it "thinks" you want to match first.  It lets you define that exactly via the order of your route definitions.

I don't know Koa.js well, but there is this in [the doc for Koa2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-router#migrating-to-7--koa-2): ***Middleware is now always run in the order declared by .use() (or .get(), etc.), which matches Express 4 API.***

Answer (score 1):

There are no specific route matching rules for `express.js` to match the routes.It goes and try to match every registered `route` with incoming request path and calls `route handlers` for all matched `paths`. Thus the following code will work.

```
app.get('/something/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`Calling with param ${req.params.id}`);
  next(); // if you remove next from here it will not call the rest of the handlers
});

app.get('/something/else', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`Calling with else`);
  next();
});
```

Output:

[image]

Thus the only way to make sure the routes match exactly, define routes in their specific order.

```
app.get('/something/else', ...handlers);
app.get('/something/:id', ...handlers);
```